# Fill the intersection area between circle and function in JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, svg, jsxgraph

I have a circle and simple function Math.cos(x)

I want the circle to be filled when it intersects with that function (fill only the upper side). But it's not working.

**Script:**

```
    // circle
    var point1 = app.board.create('point', [0,0], {size: 2, strokeWidth:2 })
    var point2 = app.board.create('point', [6,0], {size: 2, strokeWidth:2 })
    var circle = app.board.create('circle', [point1,point2], {strokeColor: "#f00", strokeWidth: 2 })
    
    // function
    var func = app.board.create('functiongraph',[function(x){ return Math.cos(x)}]);

    // intersection
    var curve = app.board.create('curve', [[], []], {strokeWidth: 0, fillColor: "#09f", fillOpacity: 0.8})
    curve.updateDataArray = function() {
        var a = JXG.Math.Clip.intersection(circle, func, this.board);
        this.dataX = a[0];
        this.dataY = a[1]
    };
    app.board.update()
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Expected output (I did it on Paint)**

[image: Expected]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily realized with the next version of JSXGraph which will be released next week: With the `inequality` element the area above the cosine curve can be marked. The inequality element is a closed curve and can be intersected with a circle. In v1.2.3, the intersection does not work because of a small bug.

For the clipping, the next version contains new elements `curveintersection`, `curveunion`, `curvedifference` which make it easier to use the methods of JXG.Math.Clip, but of course your approach with `JXG.Math.Clip` will still work.

Here is the code:

```
var f = board.create('functiongraph', ['cos(x)']);
var ineq = board.create('inequality', [f], {
            inverse: true, fillOpacity: 0.1
        });
var circ = board.create('circle', [[0,0], 4]);

var clip = board.create('curveintersection', [ineq, circ], {
            fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.6
        });
```

[image: Intersecting inequality and circle]

Actually, the inequality element does the same as enxaneta does "by hand".

Comment: Hello @Alfred Wassermann, I just tested the new version 1.3.0 and it's working exactly like i want. thank you so much for your great effort ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the next example I'm building the d attribute for the path using Math.cos().
I suppose your function may be different.
Please observe that at the end at the d attribute the path is closing the upper part of the svg canvas.
I'm using the pth inside a clipPath and I'm clipping the circle with it.

```js
let d ="M";

for(let x = -50; x<=50; x+=1){
  d+=`${x}, ${5*Math.cos(x/5)} `
}
d+="L50,-50L-50,-50z"
pth.setAttribute("d",d);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="200">
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <path id="pth"/>
  </clipPath>
  <circle r="45" clip-path="url(#clip)" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

In order to better understand how I'm building the path please take a look at the next example:

```js
let d ="M";

for(let x = -50; x<=50; x+=1){
  d+=`${x}, ${5*Math.cos(x/5)} `
}
d+="L50,-50L-50,-50z"
pth.setAttribute("d",d);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" width="200">
  <circle r="45" fill="blue"/>
  <path id="pth" fill="rgba(250,0,0,.4)"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello @enxaneta, thank you for your solution. I actually need the solution to be with JSXGraph. That math library uses svg but sadly they don't allow me to edit svg tags like in your solution.

Comment: The main idea is closing the path as I'm doing here: d+="L50,-50L-50,-50z" I suppose you'll have to change the function you are using